# Python Pandas: Dataframe.loc[] vs dataframe[] behavior difference?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm completely new to Pandas, but I was given some code that uses it, and I came across a line that looked like the following:

`df.loc[bool_array]['column_name']=0`

Looking at that code, I would expect that if I ran `df.loc[bool_array]['column_name']` to retrieve the values for the column after running said code, the resulting values would all be zero. In fact, however, this was not the case, the values remained unchanged. To actually change the values, I had to remove the `.loc` as so:

`df[bool_array]['column_name']=0`

whereupon displaying the values did, in fact, show 0 as expected, regardless of if I used `.loc` or not.

Everything I can find about `.loc` seems to indicate that it should behave essentially the same as simply doing `[]` when given a boolean array like this. What difference am I missing that explains this behavioral discrepancy?

EDIT: As pointed out by @QuangHoang in the comments, the following recommended code DOES work:

`df.loc[bool_array, 'column_name']=0`

which simplifies the question to "why doesn't the original code work"?

Comment: AFAIK, they are the same only for retrieving data, not assignment. For the latter, both are not recommended. Instead, you should do: `df.loc[bool_array, 'column_name']=0`

Comment: @QuangHoang: Would that solve the values remaining unchanged when using .loc? The point is that when I tried the original code, which used .loc, the values in the data frame did not change.

Comment: It should change the values of the original data.

Comment: @QuangHoang Ok, thanks. I'll give it a shot - it does look cleaner. Doesn't explain why the original code didn't work though.

Comment: For an explanation, see [Why does assignment fail when using chained indexing?](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing)

Comment: @QuangHoang: That link seems to be saying that the code that *worked* for me - `df[bool_array]['column_name']=0` is inherently dangerous, and may not work in all situations, which I can accept. It doesn't actually address the original code construct, `df.loc[bool_array]['column_name']=0`, however. Unless there is the implication is that it has the same pitfall as *not* using `.loc` at all...

Comment: @ibrewster I think the way I understand it that pandas sometimes creates a view of the original dataframe and sometimes it copy the subset to a new memory space in memory when using chained indexing.  The rules aren't clear when a view or a copy is used, therefore it is safer and good pratices not to use chained indexing and use .loc.

Comment: @ScottBoston: So both `df.loc[][]` and just `df[][]` (without the `.loc`) are considered "chained indexing", and so both have the same potential pitfall, and it's just an implementation detail why one worked and the other didn't? That would make sense.

Comment: Nope, only when you see '][' together can you consider this chained indexing.  .loc and .iloc are the proper methods used to access parts of a dataframe.

Comment: Actually, I do think that `df.loc[bool_series]['col_name']` is chained indexing. I could be wrong, but the fact that it doesn’t work say it may very well be the case.

Comment: Definitely, what you said, that both are assignment with chained indexing which should be avoided because you never know when an intermediate view is created